# What is difference between the Google Maps API project and credentials (key)?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have several simple Javascript Google maps on two websites. What is project here - each map or everything ? Or maybe maps on one website are one project ? But they have nothing to do with each other. How many projects should be created and how many credentials ? So far I created one project and so many credentials as maps in it. But these maps are separated, almost all different, only few of them generated by one common php, but even in this case half of them are completely different in the internet.

I don't understand this at all.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify in what context you encountered the word "project"?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should use one API Project for each "property" which is displaying maps. If you have one website where you tracking popular fishing spots and another website where you provide a directions to a local restaurant those should probably be two different API projects.

Each individual map shouldn't have it's own project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This is going to be a supplementary question. Yesterday I created already second project for maps located on second website (despite they have nothing to do with each other except location on the same domain), created new API keys for those maps and deleted their API keys in the first project, because they are in the second project now.

And maps can't be displayed any more. Google Maps  is gray and displays information:

> Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps
>   correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

The Javascript console says:

> "Google Maps API error: DeletedApiProjectMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#deleted-api-project-map-error"
>   js:32:350

The same maps work fine without API key, but don't work with the new API key !

Here is an example:

http://darz-bor.info/mapy/puszcza/

I will keep this file with not working API key 1-2 days to allow you to see it and after that will remove API key.

How to make the new API keys working ?

Comment: I created new API keys in the first project for those maps again and deleted second project. The maps work partially now - without markers. It looks a little like manual blocking by someone on the Google maps side.

Comment: ReferenceError: MarkerManager is not defined
 puszcza:267:9 But it worked few days ago. The code is the same, I only add or remove the API key. This message is visible in both cases - with or without API key.

Comment: Replaced Marker Manager by own code. Markers are visible. But the questions remain - why API keys from second project blocked those maps and why marker manager doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe someone is blocking access to Marker Manager .js file somewhere between my computer and a server where it is stored to ban my website. But telling the truth that my code is so simple and thus better than marker manager in this particular case. Number of markers in that page is small and there is no need to use such complex methods.

Answer (score 0):

go to **Maps JavaScript API** and Active this part.