# Google Maps API error: DeletedApiProjectMapError

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I have to use google map. I use below google API script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
```

And i got below Error

**Google Maps API error: DeletedApiProjectMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#deleted-api-project-map-error**

I created a New Project & New API key. But still this error came. Kindly help to solve this error.

Comment: I had the same problem, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38203980/5128459) is my solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API DeletedApiProjectMapError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199452/google-maps-api-deletedapiprojectmaperror)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yo should go to https://console.developers.google.com and after create your API KEY, go to "Google Maps JavaScript API" and just ENABLE (by default is DISABLE)

Comment: To find enable button. Goto Dashboard and click 'Enable api and services'.
Search bar will be appear and Type 'Map javascript api'. Inside that you will find Enable button.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks to google for hiding that...Arg!

Comment: Make sure you have a billing account for the Google Cloud services. If you don't you'll be asked to add your billing information.

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable Maps JavaScript API for your website.

API link: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/maps-backend.googleapis.com?q=map

[image]

Comment: This API project is not authorized to use this API. for this error, see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api

Answer (score 4):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#deverrorcodes), the **DeletedApiProjectMapError** means that your API project may have been deleted from the Google API Console. Please check the project for which you generated the API key that's included in JavaScript API loader.

Since you have already created a new API project and get a new key on the Google API Console, one workaround I found on this [forum](http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/problems-with-javascript/) is to try deactivating all plugins to see if one of them is causing a conflict.

Check this related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058270/what-is-difference-between-the-google-maps-api-project-and-credentials-key/37088190#37088190). It states that:

> I created new API keys in the first project for those maps again and deleted second project. The maps work partially now - without markers. It looks a little like manual blocking by someone on the Google maps side. Maybe someone is blocking access to Marker Manager .js file somewhere between my computer and a server where it is stored to ban my website.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I activate/enable more API Google Maps on https://console.developers.google.com and disappear this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have deleted the project in google cloud platform  of which you created an API.Regenrate Api by creating a new Project in google cloud platform.

Answer (score 0):

There some answers saying the JavaScript API needs to be enabled as it is disabled by default. That seems to have changed. It was enabled by default in my account. It did not work anyway. I had to disable and reenable the API, then it worked.

Also it is to be noted that Google says it may take a couple of minutes upon creation until the API key works, that may also have been the thing.