# Google Maps API DeletedApiProjectMapError

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I have the exact same problem like [Arul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182710/google-maps-api-error-deletedapiprojectmaperror#).

I am trying to use Google Maps API on my webpage but when I try to implement the map I've got DeletedApiProjectMapError.

First I went to the [Error Messages](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#deleted-api-project-map-error) site after I've tried many ways to include the script, like:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=API_KEY"></script> 

//or
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"></script>

//or
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

and tried to add new `API key` on the Dev site but none of them works.

Is it possible that the error isn't on my side but on Google's?

Comment: "Is it possible that the error isn't on my side but on Google's?" - unlikely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API error: DeletedApiProjectMapError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182710/google-maps-api-error-deletedapiprojectmaperror)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem.

You need to enable both the Google Maps Javascript API, **and** the Geocoding API.

https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/library

and

https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/apis/geocoding-backend.googleapis.com

Afterwards the error was `RefererNotAllowedMapError` instead of `DeletedApiProjectMapError`, but that was because I was running it on localhost - and it worked on the actual site after I added the domain in `Credentials -> Domain Verification`.

Answer (score 17):

Just to add to the reply above with an image (and this solution worked for me while still staying on the local machine), because I was a bit confused about the enabling of APIs part.

Just navigate to:
https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/apis/library

Select your project (for which you have an API)

**On the right side expand the Maps API section and click on "Google Maps Javascript API" and the "Geocoding API"**
[image]

**On the page that appears you need to click on the "play" button to enable the API**

[image]

Then you should be good to go without authorizing domains and continue working on the local machine.