# Why Google delete my Google Map Javascript API key?

Tags: api, google-maps

I tried to create a project on https://console.developers.google.com/ then I added a Google Map Javascript API and I used it on one of my websites.
But after a day I got `Google Maps API error: DeletedApiProjectMapError` and as I checked the project on Google Apis was deleted.

I tried again and it happens next day.
Is any way to figure out why Google delete my API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API DeletedApiProjectMapError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199452/google-maps-api-deletedapiprojectmaperror)

Comment: I do not think so because when I create an API key it works for one day.

Answer (score 0):

You can report this issue in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188851

Provide the project number that was deleted and somebody from Google will look into this to figure out what happened.