# How can I correctly display a google maps API on my website?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I am currently working from my localhost. I am trying to display the google maps API within my contact us form in my website. But whenever I try to implement it, an "DeletedApiProjectMapError" is shown.

In addition, how can I have the firstname and lastname of the contact form pushed to the left side of the input fields and not being center justified? How do I correctly display the google maps API? I think I have used my authentication code correctly. I have strictly followed W3Schools tutorial on google maps API, but nothing is working.

```css
.topnav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Cabin;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

/* Clear floats after rows */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    padding: 8px;
}

/* Content */
.content {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
.topnav{
  float: right;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.Who{
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-style: bold;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Cabin;
}

.Who p{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lora;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1{
  color: black;
  font-family: Cabin;
  text-align: center;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    position: relative;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background-image: url("house.jpg");
    opacity: 0.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style inputs */
input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

/* Style the container/contact section */
.con {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Create two columns that float next to eachother */
.cols {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.rws:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 traditional//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=`device-width`, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "bg">
  <div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a>
  <a href="#Who">Who</a>
  <a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class = "Who">
  <h1 id= "Who" >Who are we ?</h1>
  <p>Cabin is a website theme I created to demonstrate my skills
  as a front-end web developer.

  This website uses stock photos free of property and commercial rights.
</p>
<h1 id="Portfolio">Portfolio</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picOne.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picTwo.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picThree.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picFour.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picOne.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picTwo.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picThree.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picFour.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 id="Contact">Contact Us</h1>

  <div class="con">
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="rws">
      <div class="cols">
        <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="cols">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
          <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
          <label for="country">Country</label>
          <select id="country" name="country">
            <option value="australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            <option value="usa">USA</option>
          </select>
          <label for="subject">Subject</label>
          <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:170px"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="footer"> <p id="ft">Website created by Andrew B <br> Date created: 03/04/2016</p></div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
function myMap() {
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 12};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
  marker.setMap(map);
}

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBtU_Z1n3cfwKbDlRN_incLUZVPHof0DJA&callback=myMap"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to bring the form left to the maps ?

Just bring the `maps` `div` right next to the `form` div.

> Regarding DeletedApiProjectMapError and Loading the map in localhost

You have to enable the API in Google Console. [More info in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199452/google-maps-api-deletedapiprojectmaperror)

Updated content :

```css
.topnav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Cabin;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;

}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

/* Clear floats after rows */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    padding: 8px;
}

/* Content */
.content {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
.topnav{
  float: right;
  padding-top: 20px;

}

.Who{
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-style: bold;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Cabin;
}

.Who p{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lora;
  padding: 20px;
}

h1{
  color: black;
  font-family: Cabin;
  text-align: center;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    position: relative;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background-image: url("house.jpg");
    opacity: 0.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

/* Style the container/contact section */
.con {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Create two columns that float next to eachother */
.cols {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.rws:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

form {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

form div + div {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: right;
}
input, textarea,select {
    width: 100px;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 traditional//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=`device-width`, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "bg">
  <div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a>
  <a href="#Who">Who</a>
  <a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class = "Who">
  <h1 id= "Who" >Who are we ?</h1>
  <p>Cabin is a website theme I created to demonstrate my skills
  as a front-end web developer.

  This website uses stock photos free of property and commercial rights.
</p>
<h1 id="Portfolio">Portfolio</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picOne.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picTwo.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picThree.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picFour.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picOne.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picTwo.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picThree.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="picFour.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>My Work</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 id="Contact">Contact Us</h1>

  <div class="con">
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="rws">
      <div class="cols">
        <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="cols">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <div>
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
          </div>
          <div>
          <label for="country">Country</label>
            <select id="country" name="country">
              <option value="australia">Australia</option>
              <option value="canada">Canada</option>
              <option value="usa">USA</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:170px"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="footer"> <p id="ft">Website created by Andrew B <br> Date created: 03/04/2016</p></div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
function myMap() {
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 12};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
  marker.setMap(map);
}

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBtU_Z1n3cfwKbDlRN_incLUZVPHof0DJA&callback=myMap"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I now have the google api working but I cant get the other issue to work. I think you may have misunderstood what I am wanting to do. See the labels above the input forms, I what those labels such as first name and last name etc pushed to the left of the 2nd column.

Comment: Updated the answer @AndrewB. Hope it meets your requirements. To design the form, i just referred [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/sr-Latn/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form)